# ACL implementation for Google Cloud Datastore or Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, acl, google-cloud-datastore, firebase-security

Are there any Free ACL implementations available that I can integrate with webapp based on Google Cloud Datastore or Firebase Realtime Database?